# PhantomJS unexpected load behavior with multiple pages

Tags: coffeescript, phantomjs

i have a script (below) that scrapes a site with a 3 step process.  it works great when set to a maximum of 1 page at a time. however, when i increase that to 2 at a time things start getting wonky.  the onFinished fires earlier than i would expect and the page isn't completely loaded yet.  because of this the rest of my script breaks.  any idea why this might be happening?  i should add that i'm using the newest version (1.5).

```
MAX_PAGES = 1
### 
changing MAX_PAGES to >1 causes some pages onFinished event to fire before
the page is fully rendered.  this is evident by the fact that there are >1 images
for some pages.  i havent been able to reproduce using microsoft.com, but on some
pages i was working on the first onLoadFinished seemed to be called before the page
was actually fully loaded based on the look of the rendered images
###

newPage = (id) ->
context = {}
context.id = id
context.step = 0
context.page = require('webpage').create()
context.page.onLoadStarted = ->
    context.step++
context.page.onLoadFinished = (status) ->
    console.log status
    if status is 'success'
        context.page.render("#{context.id}_#{context.step}.png")
    else
        context.page.release()
        context.page.open('http://www.microsoft.com')
        console.log 'started loading'

newPage id for id in [1..MAX_PAGES]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the fact that each webpage within PhantomJS is using the same QNetworkAccessManager, thus, the [finished()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal is firing when each webpage object finishes loading. Modifications to PhantomJS's code might need to be made in order to fix this problem. I have noticed this before when trying to load multiple pages in parallel in PhantomJS. An application I'm working on uses QtWebkit and loads multiple pages simultaneously so I have to make sure that each webpage gets its own QNetworkAccessManager so that the finished() signals don't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 3):

To crawl multiple pages, see the example follow.js that is bundled with the library. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/follow.js

You need to use recursion to wait for the current page to load before loading the next page.

Comment: If not a recursive call as in this example, at least a callback that will trigger the next crawl.

Comment: Your link is broken :(